# Customize chromecast introduce screen text

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

According to the documentation it's possible to customize Introductory Overlay text on iOS: "The sender app can customize the text, position of the title text and the Dismiss button."
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#the_cast_ux_widgets

But I can't find any classes/properties in the SDK in order to customize it?

Comment: If you want, you can file an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) about the missing instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest iOS SDK 4.2.0 it's not possible to customize text on introduction screen.